# Keeping a row fixed to a location despite inserting rows above

Tags: excel

I have an excel document with entries, and at the bottom of each page I have a summary row. In order to comment some of the entries I have to insert new rows below them to make space. The inserted rows then pushes the summary row to the next page.

My question is therefore if it is possible to keep the summary bar fixed at the bottom of the page, despite new rows being inserted above.

Comment: Why not move the summary row to the top?

Comment: The top location is occupied with a header so that is  unfortunately not possible

Comment: If you view page break previews and drag the page break line below your summary,  Excel will automatically adjust the zoom to meet this constraint.  This might need some trial and error to get used to what it's doing.